# Custom cursors vanish / stop working seconds after loading form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, cursor

I'm trying to have a custom cursor when mousing over a certain object (.ico files as opposed to .cur) with my project. They work and appear perfectly when I load, but they disappear (or the code doesn't work) just seconds after the form loads! The files are set as an Embedded Resource, but I've tried other options and it doesn't seem to make a difference.

```
Cursor foo = new Cursor(Properties.Resources.filename.Handle);

private void form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    object.Cursor = foo;
}
```

This happens even if I change the cursor on mouseover, or use `this.Cursor` instead. What gives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are seeing the garbage collector do its job.  The first gen#0 garbage collection will destroy the Icon object returned by `Properties.Resources.filename`.  Which invalidates the handle, cursor goes bye-bye.  Using the Handle property is *not* enough to keep the object referenced, it is an IntPtr and not an object reference.

You'll need to keep the Icon object alive yourself:

```
private Icon fooIcon = Properties.Resources.filename;

public form() {
    InitializeComponent();
    object.Cursor = new Cursor(fooIcon.Handle);
    this.FormClosed += delegate { fooIcon.Dispose(); };
}
```